# What can cause MASSIVE t-statistics with relatively smaller samples?

Tags: statistical-significance, multiple-regression

I am conducting multiple regression analysis with 2 policy variables, $x_1$ and $x_2$ and their quadratics and interactions: $x_{1}^2$, $x_{2}^2$, and $x_{1}*x_{2}$. The regression equation takes the form:
$$y_i=\beta_0+\beta_{1}x_{1}+\beta_{2}x_{1}^2+\beta_{3}x_{2}+\beta_{4}x_{2}^2+\beta_{5}x_{1}x_{2}+\alpha_{1}Dummy1_{i}+\alpha_{2}Dummy2_{i}+\alpha_{3}Year_{i}+u_i$$
Where the $\beta$’s are scalar coefficients and the $\alpha$’s are vectors of coefficients. Following, $Dummy1_{i}$ is a set of 6 dummy variables indicating one category, and $Dummy2_{i}$ is another set of 7 dummy variables, and $Year_i$ is a set if 7 dummy variables for each year. It is a cross-sectional data set where I have collected around 50 experiments that each have between 2 and 30 observations each. This particular regression has 215 observations.

One of the 6 first dummy variables has a t-statistic of 1.150e+15, which is utterly ridiculous. Another dummy variable in the same category has no t-statistic because the standard error cannot be computed as there are less observations than the number of variables. I cannot figure out why I have such a massive t-statistic especially since the number of observations isn't that high. Any tips or direction would be extremely helpful!

Comment: What would be ridiculous is computing such statistics for models with more parameters than data: they will be overfit; the resulting estimates of residual variance will differ from zero only by accumulated floating point error; and the t-statistics will divide the parameter estimates by square roots of those approximate zeros.  How many parameters, then, does your model use to fit its 215 observations?

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I was clear enough. The dummy variable with no standard error takes values equal to 1 less times than the number of parameters. I believe the model has 38 parameters in total, most of which being shift parameters (shifting the intercept). I am unsure still though, the dummy variable (with no std. error) is an indicator of whether or not the observations come from a study that analyzed a particular crop, say, rice.

Comment: Are you sure about the parameter count?  Based on your description, the dummy variables alone contribute at least 53 parameters plus the "20-odd" variables for each year, which contribute *at least* another 19 parameters *per year* (over how many years?)--even if they are only binary.  Could you give a more specific description of you model?

Comment: 26 parameters, sorry I just guessed about the year dummy variables. Forgot that its not balanced (don't have one for every year over the time span).

Comment: I guess that a better depiction of the model (for instance with an equation) would not hurt. Just one question: do you cluster the standard errors ? If yes, try without clustering. Does the standard error get reasonnable values when you do not cluster any longer?

Comment: Thats a good point, i do cluster my standard errors. I will try without. Also I will update the question with an equation

Comment: @Brennan : Then, does removing the clustering change something ?